# MultipartMemoryStreamProvider: filename?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I already asked here how I can read uploaded files in Web Api without the need to save them.
This question was answered with the MultipartMemoryStreamProvider, but how do I get the file name with this method to derive the type of the uploaded file from it?

Kind regards

Comment: A link to the other question, please.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is an example in this DotNetNuke Code [here](https://dotnetnuke.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Community/DotNetNuke.Web/InternalServices/FileUploadController.cs) (See the `PostFile()` method).

**Updated** based on @FilipW comment...

Get the content item you require and then access the filename property.

Something like this :

```
        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
             ContinueWith(o =>
                 {
                     //Select the appropriate content item this assumes only 1 part
                     var fileContent = provider.Contents.SingleOrDefault();

                     if (fileContent != null)
                     {
                         var fileName = fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                     }
                 });//Ending Bracket
```

Comment: just check headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty); - there is no "postfile" header :)

Comment: @FilipW Indeed - my ignorance showing through there. Was trying to explain how to find the correct HttpContent based on the fields name, incorrectly assumed POSTFILE was a standard, and certainly shouldn't have used the term header to describe it. Left the content selection up to the OP now.