# Web API : Read the image send from the app

Tags: c#-4.0, file-upload, blob, azure-storage, asp.net-web-api

I need to read the file been send from the Ios app to the Azure web api.

I need to upload that to the blob and keep the Uri.

Can anybody suggest me the code to accept the file been send.

```
 /// <summary>
    ///This is to upload the image file for the user profile.
    /// </summary>
    ///<param name="userRegId"> </param>
    ///<returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public Response ImageUpload(int  userRegId)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = new Response();
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                response.status = CommonHandler.GetInvalidStatus();
            }
            else
            {

                //here i want to read the file and upload it to blob.


                string fileName =Request.Files[0].FileName;//unable to do this. Here i want to know ho to read the file
                string uniqueBlobName = string.Format("{0}/{1}", constants.pdf, fileName);
                CloudBlobClient blobStorage = cloudClasses.CreateOrGetReferenceOfBlobStorage(constants.pdf);
                CloudBlockBlob blob = cloudClasses.ClouBblockBlobPropertySetting(blobStorage, uniqueBlobName, ".pdf");
                blob.UploadFromStream(Request.Files[0].InputStream);//unable to do this.  Here i want to know ho to read the file
                response.status = CommonHandler.GetSuccessStatus();
            }
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(Log4NetLogger.Category.Exception, "Error in : APIController.ImageUpload :>> Exception message: " + ex.Message);
            return new Response { status = CommonHandler.GetFailedStatus(ex.Message) };

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yao Huang Lin wrote a blog post on how to produce a Web API file service backed by Azure blob storage. You can find it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/07/02/asp-net-web-api-and-azure-blob-storage.aspx).

Comment: Can't we read the file simply from the stream as how we do in normal ashx service handlers. I just need the code to read the file.. uploading to cloud blob is not a problem.

Comment: You need to use a [MultipartStreamProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartstreamprovider(v=vs.108).aspx). Some examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475248/multipartmemorystreamprovider-filename) and [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1842441.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code,

```
var streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
                Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
                foreach (var content in streamProvider.Contents)
                {
                    if (content != null)
                    {
                        if (content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName != null)
                        {
                            var fileName =
                                content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.
                                                                                              Empty);
                            Stream stream = content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                            CloudBlobContainer blobStorage = BlobHandler.GetBlobStorage("profileimage");
                            CloudBlockBlob blob = BlobHandler.BlobPropertySetting(blobStorage,
                                                                                  Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLower() +
                                                                                  fileName);
                            blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
                            response = ProfileHandler.ImageUpdate(userRegId, blob.Uri);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

For the blobHandler

```
public static CloudBlobContainer GetBlobStorage(string cloudBlobContainerName)
    {
        CloudBlobContainer container;
        try
        {
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("StorageConnectionString");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(cloudBlobContainerName); //profile
            container.CreateIfNotExist();
            var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
            permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
            container.SetPermissions(permissions);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(Log4NetLogger.Category.Exception, "Error in : BlobHandler.GetBlobStorage :>> Exception message: " + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        return container;
    }
    public static CloudBlockBlob BlobPropertySetting(CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobClientReferenceName, string blobContentName)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = cloudBlobClientReferenceName.GetBlockBlobReference(blobContentName);

        //blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
        return blob;
    }
```

Hope this will help someone..

Comment: How Image getting mapped to your web api method? can you please show your api action signature as well?